# How to deal with multiple identical classes in a project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio

In a multi-tenant project, tenants could have different UI and functionality.  To that end, there is a structure like this:

```
TenantA
  SiteHeader.ts (class named SiteHeader)
TenantB
  SiteHeader.ts (class named SiteHeader)
... 20 other tenants
```

On the web page, the .js declaration dynamically generates (server-side) the reference to the correct tenant:

```
<script src="../{CurrentTenant}/SiteHeader.js"></script>
```

On this same page, Main.ts needs to reference the correct SiteHeader.  Since I can't (and don't want to) have `import {SiteHeader} from 'TenantA/SiteHeader'` and `import {SiteHeader} from 'TenantB/SiteHeader'` and 20 others, I am forced to simply declare it as a var, which points to whatever js was loaded by the parent page:

```
declare var SiteHeader;
```

However, it causes Duplicate identifier errors in each SiteHeader.ts.  And occasionally in the Main.ts as well.  I am able to drop down to the command line and compile each SiteHeader.ts manually, but it's chore.

How can I resolve this sort of situation?

Not that it matters much, trying to bring TypeScript to an old school WebForms project in Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 1):

You could create `interface SiteHeader` and make all tenants implement it. But I am not sure how runtime would work with `<script>` tag in combination with external modules. Have you considered [internal modules (namespaces)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) or using [dynamic `import()`](https://2ality.com/2017/01/import-operator.html) (should be supported in TypeScript)?

Comment: I can't do `<script type="module" ...>`, because, unfortunately, IE is on the supported browsers list.  If that is what you are referring to.

Comment: No. I have added links to documentation to be more clear.

Comment: I tried that.  And unfortunately it doesn't work with IE.  TypeScript doesn't generate JS for the `import` statements and just relies on either the browser or webpack to support it.

Comment: Yes, for `import()` you need some kind of loader (like webpack, or for example require.js). But for namespaces nothing extra is needed.